# Deformation gradient of a 2D manifold

Tags: coordinate-systems, continuum-mechanics

I have a 2D manifold (triangle) defined by points $\vec{X}=(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ in the reference configuration and have  $X_3=C$ (moreover, the reference configuration is not the unitary simplex ); I apply the transformation: 
\begin{align}
\vec{x}=\vec{\phi}(\vec{X})=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1= X_1\\
x_2= X_2\\
x_3=\alpha X_3
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
I'm expecting as deformation gradient  the unit matrix $\mathrm{I}_{3\times 3}$, however, if i stright derive $\vec{\phi}$, what I obtain is:

\begin{align}
F_{ij}=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_j}=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 \\
0 &0 &\alpha
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

If, however, I consider a unit simplex, the mapping between the unit simplex and the reference configuration $\vec{X}$ and the mapping between the unit simplex and the current configuration $\vec{x}$; if I define the covariant basis for the reference configuration: $C=[\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,\vec{A}_3]$ where:$\vec{A}_3= (\vec{A}_1\times \vec{A}_2)/\|(\vec{A}_1\times \vec{A}_2)\| $ and the covariant basis for the current configuration: $c=[\vec{a}_1,\vec{a}_2,\vec{a}_3]$ where:$\vec{a}_3= (\vec{a}_1\times \vec{a}_2)/\|(\vec{a}_1\times \vec{a}_2)\| $; when I evaluate the deformation gradient as:
$F=cC^{-1}$ I obtain the right solution: $F=\mathrm{I}_{3\times3}$

What I'm forgetting in the derivation of the deformation gradient? 
Or, alternatively, why $F=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_j}$ and $F=cC^{-1}$ differ?

Thanks

Comment: That is the correct answer. Why are you expecting the unit matrix?

Comment: Because all the points lie on the plane  $X_3=C$, thus the triangle in the current configuration will lie on the plane $x_3=C\alpha$; hence, we have a rigid body translation which is not represented in the deformation gradient. Any Idea?

Comment: That is not the definition of deformation gradient.  The X are initial body coordinates, and the x are the global location of points in the body as it moved.  You get non-trivial def-grad for rigid rotations.  So, first question is, are the Xi 3-vectors for each point in the triangle?  You have a point, not a collection of points.  Second, is x3 --> Ca equivalent to a translation?  It looks more like a conformal transformation.  What would this do to an infinitesimal thickness, dx3, of a piece of material?

Comment: $X_i$ are the coordinates of the point triangles in the initial configuration  $P=(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ and the manifold is 2D  (e.g., I can describe it with only 2 independent coordinates, say $(\xi_1,\xi_2) $ (and no thickness). 
If I consider a mapping between the unitary simplex and either X or x, define the covariant basis basis $C=(A_1, A_2, A_3)$  and  $c=(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ ($C_3 $ and $c_3$ unit normals),  deformation gradient is $F=cC^{-1}$ (=$I_{3\times3}$ in this case).  Why derivation of $\vec{x}$ with respect to $\vec{X}$ yields a different expression for F?